# Why can't I call a Java method of an imported android platform api class in cordova cusotm plugin

Tags: java, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am creating an App with Ionic and in order to load assets that are working with Play Asset Delivery I need to access the android native code by creating a cordova Plugin. I need to add those [three lines of code](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-java#install-time-delivery). In order to achieve this I imported the Android Platform APIs that contain those methods and classes.

Plugins Java file:

```
package cordova.plugin.hello;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

//My Imports
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import java.io.InputStream; 

public class hello extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        Context context = createPackageContext("io.ionic.starter", 0);
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        InputStream is = assetManager.open("pack1");
    }
}
```

When building the App I get this error:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
C:\Users\LUM\appAsset\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\cordova\plugin\hello\hello\hello.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        Context context = createPackageContext("io.ionic.starter", 0);
                          ^
  symbol:   method createPackageContext(String,int)
  location: class hello
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
```

I am very new to app development and all possible solutions that I found on the Internet created different Errors and while going further away from the three lines of code you can see in the first linked article. For example adding `this.cordova.getActivity()` and call `createPackageContext("io.ionic.starter", 0);` on that. That created even more errors. Same with other fixing tries.

I get it that it's normal to get Errors even after fixing others, but it would really help me out if you can help me out with what I am fundamentally doing wrong with the code.

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
NodeJS            : v12.18.3
npm               : 6.14.6
OS                : Windows 10
Gradle            : 6.6.1
Ionic Framework   : @ionic/angular 5.3.3
Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0
```

Comment: This line is your problem: Context context = createPackageContext("io.ionic.starter", 0); Either you misspelled the name of the method, or you're passing invalid parameters.

Comment: @Stultuske The Error says that it can't find the symbol. I am guessing that I am calling it wrong or imported it wrong

Comment: it's nothing to do with imports. Either that method is in your current class (which it isn't) or it is in the inheritance hierarchy (starting with the CordovaPlugin class)

Comment: The method createPackageContext is part of android.content.Context that I imported. In the three line code example they do not import this. Do you know how I can access the mothod? Maybe "extends Context". The Method is not static therefore I can not just go like Context.createPackageContext

Comment: if it's not static, you'll need to call that method on an instance of Context, not before you have such an instance. Does your class need to extend Context, or CordovaPlugin?

Comment: It needs to extend CordovaPlugin. (I forgot you can only extend one calss). What confuses me is that the method returns a Context: " Context context = createPackageContext("io.ionic.starter", 0); "

Comment: why would that be confusing? But still, you'll need an instance of context to call it on

Comment: @Drakeless was you able to create a plugin? Can you share?

Comment: @AntonEregin Forget the whole Plugin thing. Change the asset path in a way that it will be in a directory that the app can access. ([src/main/assets]/www/assets/[...])

Answer (score 1):

[@Stultuske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2636929/stultuske) is right - `createPackageContext()` is an instance method on the `android.content.Context` class so you need to call it on an existing class instance.
You can use the application context instance; try this:

```
Context context = this.cordova
        .getActivity()
        .getApplicationContext()
        .createPackageContext("io.ionic.starter", 0);
```

Comment: `Context context = this.cordova
        .getActivity()
        .getApplicationContext();` Seems to work just fine. No need to add the Apps Name. That is also very usefull beacause then I can just add this plugin to any App without needing to edit the plugin itself or send the apps reverse domain name as an argument.